# Как исправить спам алертов

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть код, который вызывает алерт с ошибкой, но как сделать, так чтобы больше одного алерта не приходило, ибо заметил такой баг, что я могу вызвать хоть 100 алертов нажав на кнопку отправить

```js
$('form#update').submit(async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()

    const target = e.target;

    try {
        await $.ajax(target.action, {
            method: 'POST',
            data: $(target).serialize(),
            timeout: 3000,
        })
        location.reload()
    } catch (e) {
        const element = document.createElement('h4');
        element.classList.add('alert', 'alert-danger', 'mt-4');

        switch (e.status) {
            case 400:
                element.innerText = e.responseJSON.message;
                break;
            case 401:
                window.location.href = 'login';
                break;
            case 0:
                element.innerText = 'Сервер не отвечает.';
                break;
        }

        target.parentElement.append(element);

        // То удалить
    }
});
```

Comment: А лучше всего - не позволять отправлять форму, пока предыдущий запрос не закончился.

Answer (score 1):

Самый простой вариант - удалять alert перед выводом

```
...

document.querySelector('.alert-danger').remove();
target.parentElement.append(element);
```